# Jira Xray Test Execution Report not reliable

Tags: jira, report

[Xray](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/About+Xray) is an addon for [jira](/questions/tagged/jira) and Xray offers a [Test Execution Report](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Test+Executions+Report).
The basis for the report can be a saved filter or a [Test Plan](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY730/Test+Plan). A Test Plan can have n [Test Executions](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY730/Test+Execution).

Example
[image: Test Execution Report]

As you can see in the image 5 Executions are associated to this report

```js
    CALC-1972    // Execution 1972 of project CALC
    CALC-1969    
    CALC-1968    
    CALC-1966    
    CALC-1961
```

In my setup i have a random behaviour.

**Want**

```js
   FOO-123 // Execution 123 of project FOO
   FOO-124 
   BAR-987 // Execution 987 of project BAR
```

**Got**
Sometimes

> 1. FOO-123
> 2. FOO-124

And someitimes

> 1. BAR-987

Does anyone know why the report sometimes shows all executions and sometimes does not show them?
What can be done to make the report reliable?